# ¿Cómo cerrar un bucle cuando usuario presione "x"?

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo en python. Estoy haciendo un programa donde pregunte a un usuario cumpleaños con nombres, días y mes pero, en lugar de preguntarle cuantos cumpleaños quiere anotar, quiero hacer que nada más los ponga y cuando termine de poner los nombre, días y mes que quiera presione `x` y siga con el resto del programa, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Este es mi código:

```
times=int(input("Cuantos nombres? "))

cumples = {}

for i in range(0,times):
    nombre = input("Nombre? ")
    dia = input("dia de cumpleaños? ")
    mes = input("mes de cumpleaños? ")

    lista = cumples.get(mes, [])
    lista.append((nombre,dia)) 
    cumples[mes] = lista


for k, v in cumples.items():
  for t in v:
    print("mes {0}: día: {1} nombre: {2}".format(k, t[1], t[0]))

print(cumples)
```

aquí uso diccionarios para ordenar los cumpleaños con nombres mes y días. Después los imprimo en orden mes, día y el nombre también.

Tengo un bucle para que el usuario ponga, por ejemplo: 5 nombres y le pregunta los nombres, día, y mes 5 veces pero lo que quiero hacer es que nada más ponga nombre, día, mes hasta que presione `x` y después ordenarlos con el resto del programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un ciclo `while` infinito en vez de un `for`. Luego simplemente rompe el ciclo si se ingresa "x". Algo así:

```
cumples = {}

while True:
    nombre = input("Ingrese un nuevo nombre o 'X' para terminar: ")
    if nombre.lower() == "x":
        break
    dia = input("dia de cumpleaños? ")
    mes = input("mes de cumpleaños? ")

    lista = cumples.get(mes, [])
    lista.append((nombre,dia)) 
    cumples[mes] = lista


for k, v in cumples.items():
  for t in v:
    print("mes {0}: día: {1} nombre: {2}".format(k, t[1], t[0]))

print(cumples)
```

También puedes hacer que si no se ingresa nada y se pulsa "Enter" (una cadena vacía) se salga:

```
while True:
    nombre = input("Ingrese un nuevo nombre o pulse 'Enter' para terminar: ")
    if not nombre:
        break
```

Si quieres puedes hacer uso de [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) para tu diccionario:

```
from collections import defaultdict

cumples = defaultdict(list)
while True:
    nombre = input("Ingrese un nuevo nombre o pulse 'Enter' para terminar: ")
    if not nombre:
        break
    dia = input("dia de cumpleaños? ")
    mes = input("mes de cumpleaños? ")

    cumples[mes].append((nombre,dia)) 



for k, v in cumples.items():
  for t in v:
    print("mes {0}: día: {1} nombre: {2}".format(k, t[1], t[0]))

print(cumples)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda para terminar mi programa, gracias